# Getting IOS signing key information

Tags: java, android, ios, security, robovm

I have an Android and IOS cross-platform app. It needs some data for security purposes that prevents decompiled app to work after recompiling. The idea is to use info about key that is used to sign apps. I've found a way to get some key by using signature, now I'm struggling to find a solution for IOS. Is there something available to use in IOS app? What do you think is the best approach? Is it possible for potential hacker to get same information from built apk/ipa?

P.S. I'm using Java/Kotlin for Android and same + robovm for IOS. If you are not familiar with robovm, but ok with native development - feel free to answer - I'll translate.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity

Comment: iOS apps are signed by Apple before the are published in their app store. What signature certificate is used for signing by Apple is AFAIK not specified by Apple (and it can change at any time).